# laravel метод save() выдает ошибку

Tags: php, laravel

Есть массив расписания:

```
public function index()
{
    $club_id = 1;
    $data = [];
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= 12; $i++ ) {

        $row = null;
        $row = Row::whereRaw( 'club_id = ' . $club_id . ' and row_weight = ' . $i )->first();
        if ($row) {
            $columns = Column::whereRaw( 'row_id = ' . $row->id )->get();
            $rowExit = $this->formStubRow();

            foreach ( $columns as $column ) {
                $column_id = $column->id;
                $time = $column->time;
                $gym = $column->gym;
                $status = $column->status;
                $worker_name = Worker::find( $column->worker_id )->worker_name;
                $service_title = Service::find( $column->service_id )->service_title;
                $rowExit[ $column->day ][ $gym ] = [ ];

                    {
                    $rowExit[ $column->day ][ $gym ] = [
                        'id'        => $column_id,
                        'time'      => $time,
                        'gym'       => $gym,
                        'group'     => $service_title,
                        'trainer'   => $worker_name,
                        'status'    => $status,
                        'activate'  => true
                    ];
                }
            }

            array_push( $data, $rowExit );
        } else {
            array_push( $data, $this->formStubRow() );
        }

    }
    return view( 'api.timetable.index', compact('columns'), [ 'data' => $data ] );
}
```

его вывод через view:

```
@foreach( $data as $row )
    <div class='row' style='clear:both;width:1190px;'>
    @foreach( $row as $day=>$gymArray )
        <div class='cell'
             style='width:170px;float:left;border-right:1px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;border-top:1px solid black;text-align: center;min-height:300px;max-height:370px;overflow: auto'>
            @foreach( $gymArray as $gym=>$gymInfo )
                <div class='gym' id="timetable-cell-gym" style='clear:both'>
                   <a href="{{ isset($gymInfo['id']) ? url('api/columns/'.$gymInfo['id' ].'/edit') : '#' }}"> <p>{{ $gymInfo[ 'time' ] or '' }}</p><hr style="width:20%;margin-top: -8px;"/></a>
                        <strong  id="group-name" style="margin-top: -5px">{{ $gymInfo[ 'group' ] or '' }}</strong><br>
                        {{ $gymInfo[ 'trainer' ] or '' }} <br>
                        <p > {{ $gymInfo[ 'status' ] or '' }}</p>
                        <small id="gym-name">{{ $gym or '' }}</small>
                </div>
                <hr style='width:90%'/>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

В контроллере методы редактирования и обновления:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $columns = Column::findOrFail($id)->get();

    $trainers = Worker::get()->toArray();
    $trainersArray = [];
    foreach( $trainers as $trainer ){
        $trainersArray[ $trainer[ 'id'] ] = $trainer[ 'worker_name' ];
    }

    $groups = Service::get()->toArray();
    $groupsArray = [];
    foreach( $groups as $group ){
        $groupsArray [ $group['id'] ] = $group[ 'service_title' ];
    }
    $status = [
            'status-open' => 'группа открыта',
            'status-gain' => 'группа в наборе',
            'status-closed' => 'группа закрыта'
    ];
    return view( 'api.timetable.edit', compact('columns', 'status'),[ 'groups' => $groupsArray, 'trainers' => $trainersArray] );
}

public function update()
{
    try {
    $id = Input::get( 'id' );
    $columns = Column::findOrFail($id);
    $columns->time = Input::get( 'time' );
    $columns->service_id = Input::get( 'service_title' );
    $columns->worker_id = Input::get( 'worker_name' );
    $columns->status = Input::get( 'status' );
    $columns->save();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
        abort(404);
    }

    \Session::flash('my-messages', ['success' => 'ячейка успешно обновлена']);
    return redirect('api/columns');
}
```

Я уже не понимаю что именно тут сделал не так. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: @totorro ошибка переросла в другую может подскажете и в этом? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/467903/195124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При использовании метода `findOrFail()` делать `get()` уже не нужно.

Замените строку

```
$column = Column::findOrFail($id)->get();
```

на

```
$column = Column::findOrFail($id);
```

И если Вы используете метод `findOrFail()` следовательно предполагается что возможно возникновение ошибки. Эту ошибку тоже нужно обрабатывать.

```
try
{
    $column = Column::findOrFail($id);
}
catch(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    //тут обрабатываете пойманную ошибку (пишете в лог/что либо еще, ниже просто пример)
    dd($e)
}
```

**UPD**

Ошибка

> No query results for model [App\Column]

возникает из за того что Вы не передаете `id`, добавьте в форму скрытое поле

```
{!! Form::hidden('id',  значение id) !!}
```

**UPD2**

Вы не правильно передаете переменную в Ваш именованный маршрут. Замените:

```
<a href="{{ isset($gymInfo['id']) ? url('api/columns/'.$gymInfo['id' ].'/edit') : '#' }}"> <p>{{ $gymInfo[ 'time' ] or '' }}</p><hr style="width:20%;margin-top: -8px;"/></a>
```

На:

```
<a href="{{ isset($gymInfo['id']) ? URL::route('api/columns/edit', array($gymInfo['id'])) : '#' }}"> <p>{{ $gymInfo[ 'time' ] or '' }}</p><hr style="width:20%;margin-top: -8px;"/></a>
```

Comment: Таким образом выпадает ошибка No query results for model [App\Column]
А если методом first то редактируется только первая запись

Comment: и еще такой момент, я не вижу в вашей таблице поля, где бы Вы передавали `id`.

Comment: дополнил данные по таблице. Я пытался передать id но видимо не верно.

Comment: а куда форма делась? ошибка возникает в методе `edit()` или `updaye()`?

Comment: в методе edit если $column = Column::findOrFail($id);
в методе update как говорил ранее обновляется первый элемент таблицы при использовании $column = Column::first($id);

Comment: что показывает `dd($id);` перед `$column = Column::findOrFail($id);`

Comment: выдает только null

Comment: ну вот ) ошибку мы нашли, теперь нужно понять причину. Сбросьте пример урл который генерит этот код - `<a href="{{ isset($gymInfo['id']) ? url('api/columns/'.$gymInfo['id' ].'/edit') : '#' }}"> ... </a>`. И до кучи маршрут, который это все обрабатывает

Comment: http://fit.dev/api/columns/184/edit
ну и роуты на всякий случай:
Route::get('columns/{id}/edit',  [
  'uses' => 'TimetableControllerTwo@edit',
  'as' => 'api.columns.edit',
 ]);
 Route::put('columns/', [
  'uses' => 'TimetableControllerTwo@update',
  'as' => 'api.columns.update',
 ]);

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте у себя

Comment: теперь Undefined variable: id (View: /var/www/fit/resources/views/api/timetable/index.blade.php)

Comment: замените `$id` на `$gymInfo['id']` ту я немного промазал ) `<a href="{{ isset($gymInfo['id']) ? URL::route('api/columns/edit', array($gymInfo['id'])) : '#' }}">...</a>`

Comment: теперь так вот Route [api/columns/edit] not defined.

Comment: А если переписать роут так? `Route::get('columns/edit/{id}', [ 'as' => 'api.columns.edit', 'uses' => 'TimetableControllerTwo@edit', ]);` пс: а использование именованых маршрутов это принципиальный вопрос?

Comment: в данном случае да, а в принципе обычно не делаю так

Comment: Route [api/columns/edit] not defined теперь так)

Comment: а если так - `<a href="{{ isset($gymInfo['id']) ? URL::route('api/columns/edit', array('id' => $gymInfo['id'])) : '#' }}">...</a>`

Comment: то же самое Route [api/columns/edit] not defined

Comment: подожди у тебя же в маршруте точки... может в этом затык. Замени роут на `Route::get('columns/{id}/edit', [ 'as' => 'api/columns/edit', 'uses' => 'TimetableControllerTwo@edit', ]);` а еще лучше на что то подобное `Route::get('columns/{id}/edit', [ 'as' => 'test', 'uses' => 'TimetableControllerTwo@edit', ]);` и вызови так `<a href="{{ isset($gymInfo['id']) ? URL::route('test', array('id' => $gymInfo['id'])) : '#' }}">...</a>` и посмотрим что будет

Comment: все таблицу вывело, и теперь мы вернулись к : No query results for model [App\Column]

Comment: чтобы в методе  `edit($id)` получить доступ к `$id` сделай `$id = Session:get( 'id' );` и из сигнатуры метода убери `$id` - `edit()`

Comment: сейчас проблема в методе update, так как все еще выводит No query results for model [App\Column]. При нажатии кнопки подтверждающей обновление

Comment: ну так потому что ты не передаеш туда `$id` в форме добавил скрітое поле с айдишником? `{!! Form::hidden('id', твое  значение id) !!}`

Comment: что то вроде {!! Form::hidden('id', $columns->id) !!} ?

Comment: если `$columns->id` это твое айди то да

Comment: та же ошибка остается

Comment: 1. посмотри в исходном коде страницы есть ли скрытое поле с ид
2. если есть посмотри есть ли там значение
3. если есть то ли ты значение ожидаеш
4. посмотри получаеш ли ты его в твоем методе апдейт
5. посмотри есть ли по такому айди запись в базе

Comment: Все такой же null и при попытке first опять редактирование одной ячейки

Comment: что значит такой же нул. на каком из описанных выше этапов ты потерял ид?

Comment: public function update()
    {
        try {
        $id = Input::get( 'id' );
        $columns = Column::findOrFail($id);
        $columns->time = Input::get( 'time' );
        $columns->service_id = Input::get( 'service_title' );
        $columns->worker_id = Input::get( 'worker_name' );
        $columns->status = Input::get( 'status' );
        $columns->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
            abort(404);
        }

Всю ночь не спал над этим думал

Comment: еще раз, если ты в функции выше не получаеш айди заначит ты его гдето теряеш по пути. Давай по порядку. Напиши каке поле у тебя в форме генерит это код ` {!! Form::hidden('id', $columns->id) !!}`

Comment: <input name="_method" value="PUT" type="hidden">
<input name="_token" value="9IJkCUkUEZEdIUSkGHvDIhLsCg6hsJRD3orysw0W" type="hidden">

Comment: должно быть это `<input name="id" value="твое значение ид" type="hidden">` если этого нет ты не правильно сотавил форму. Можно попробовать указать поле ид не через blade а явно. Тоесть `<input name="id" value="{!! $columns->id !!}" type="hidden">`

Comment: единственное более менее похожее <input name="id" value="184" type="hidden"> и то выдает так же в любой ячейке

Comment: ну так в этом и проблема, `$columns->id` это индивидуальный айдишник для каждой колонки? видимо нет иначе поле `value` было бы везде разное

Comment: $columns->id по идее индивидуальный для каждой ячейки

Comment: чудес не бывает, смотрите под отладчиком. Ибо если в каждой ячейке `<input name="id" value="{!! $columns->id !!}" type="hidden">` выдает вот это `<input name="id" value="184" type="hidden">` значит `$columns->id` везде одинаковый